# Why show hide option does not work using this query

Tags: html, jquery

Why show hide option does not work?
The idea is to be able to use class name with space like `class="BXXX 01"`
where `XXX 01` is dynamic data

Here is not working jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/master1991/fq32Lhe9/36/

```js
$(document).on('keyup', ".BenterInput", function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('data-item');
  var num = $(this).val();

  if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
    $("a[class='B" + item + "']").show();
  } else {
    $("a[class='B" + item + "']").hide();
  }

  console.log(item + ' ' + num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qInDocBXXX"></div>
<input type="text" name="valueToAdd" data-item="XXX" class="BenterInput">

<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs add_row BXXX" data-but="B" style="display: none;">XXX</a>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. What is expected output for what input?

Comment: The JSFiddle is complete, why did you leave essential lines of code out of the question itself??

Comment: @mplungjan link should show when numbers is entered and hide when deleted

Comment: @DanielBeck I had the same that was on fiddle. Fidle is not working as a tag does not show up

Comment: @user17571799 before mplungjan edited your question it was missing the `<input>`  and its attributes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is that the actual className is  `btn btn-default btn-xs add_row BXXX AB` so you cannot use

```
$("a[class='BXXX AB']")
```

to make your code work, you would have to do

```
$("a[class='btn btn-default btn-xs add_row B" + item + "']").show();
```

but that would assume the order of your classes stayed the same.

I suggest you instead toggle the element on and off using the isNumeric instead of show/hide

NOTE: If you have `data-item="XXX.AB"` then it works without the split

```js
$(document).on('keyup', ".BenterInput", function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('data-item');
  var num = $(this).val();
  $(`a.B${item.split(" ").join(".")}`).toggle($.isNumeric(num));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qInDocBXXX"></div>
<input type="text" name="valueToAdd" data-item="XXX AB" class="BenterInput">

<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs add_row BXXX AB" data-but="B" hidden>XXX</a>
```

Comment: Nope. .. THis still does not show link when numbers entered on input

Comment: it should show up no matter what number is entered. And xxx could be a name like XXX or XXX AB or XXX AB 01 no matter

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/master1991/8t2793m1/ Your code but class with space. .. And not working anymore! XXX AB is a dynamic part from database

Comment: Yes now this seems to be working! But why `$("a[class='B" + item + "']").show();` does not work? I have typed it correct.

Comment: So i have to include all parts for it to work ? WOW just tried with all classes. .. but i do not get it. .. why couldnt i use just part of class?

Comment: See update for explanation

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to be able to use class name with space like class="BXXX 01"

That's not a class name with a space in it; that's two classes.

Matching against the entire classNames list is fragile, because you're having to include a whole bunch of irrelevant classnames, and if any of them differ or are missing the match will fail. It will also break if the classnames are correct but happen to come in a different order:

```css
div[class="a b c"] {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="a b c">One</div>
<div class="b c a">two</div>
```

I would strongly recommend against that approach.

Instead you can just match the two specific classes you're interested in:

```
 a.BXXX.AB {...}
```

...or in your case (assuming `item` contains the string "XXX AB")

```
 $("a.B"+item.replace(/ /g,"."))
```

Comment: Is this not exactly what I say in my for some reason [downvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200477/295783)

Comment: ...no?  I wrote this answer in response to yours, to point out that `a[class='btn btn-default btn-xs add_row B" + item + "']` is very fragile

Comment: But that was not my answer That was my explanation why his code did not work. Then I answered with a split/join version where you use regexp